# How to add custom ApplicationContextInitializer to a spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

One way to add custom ApplicationContextInitializer to spring web application is to add it in the web.xml file as shown below.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>somepackage.CustomApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But since I am using spring boot, is there any way I don't have to create web.xml just to add CustomApplicationContextInitializer?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can register them in `META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
com.example.YourInitializer
```

You can also add them on your `SpringApplication` before running it

```
application.addInitializers(YourInitializer.class);
application.run(args);
```

Or on the builder

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApp.class)
    .initializers(YourInitializer.class);
    .run(args);
```

It wasn't obvious from the doc at first glance so I opened [#5091](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5091) to check.

Comment: Or `context.initializer.classes=com.example.YourInitializer` in a properties file. I like this approach because then you can enable/disable initializers via environment specific properties files

Comment: @JeffSheets it works and it's the most convenient for me, you should post it as an answer

Comment: [Spring Boot documentation reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)

Answer (score 26):

Another approach is to use `context.initializer.classes=com.example.YourInitializer` in a properties/yml file. I like this approach because then you can enable/disable initializers via environment specific props files.

It is mentioned only briefly in the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)

Comment: I cannot find this approach in the mentioned doc (anymore?).

Comment: Oh interesting, yes it looks like they removed it from the docs. It probably still works? But I don't have an active project to try it out on so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using @ContextConfiguration annotation at class level like this:

```html
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [TestContainersInitializer::class])
```

This way is useful to add this initializer to a test class for example to start docker containers before executing tests.

Comment: Just to be clear: This approach is only applicable to integration tests (i. e. `@SpringBootTest`) as mentioned in the class' JavaDoc.