# How to use "Functional bean definition Kotlin DSL" with Spring Boot and Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

At https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/context/support/BeanDefinitionDsl.kt the comment shows how to define Spring Beans via the new "Functional bean definition Kotlin DSL". I also found https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional. However, this example uses just *plain* Spring and not Spring *Boot*. Any hint how to use the DSL together with Spring *Boot* is appreciated.

Comment: Have you just tried it out, e.g. by putting this bean definition into a controller (which is discovered by spring boot)?

Comment: Yes, I tried a `@Configuration` class with an `@Bean` method returning the result of `beans {...}`. Then I got the exception `"... No qualifying bean of type '...' available ..."` when I remove `@Service` and declare the service class inside the `beans {...}` lambda above.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Spring Boot is based on Java Config, but should allow experimental support of user-defined [functional bean declaration DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/kotlin.html#functional-bean-declaration-dsl) via `ApplicationContextInitializer` support as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217354/how-to-add-custom-applicationcontextinitializer-to-a-spring-boot-application).

In practice, you should be able to declare your beans for example in a `Beans.kt` file containing a `beans()` function.

```
fun beans() = beans {
    // Define your bean with Kotlin DSL here
}
```

Then in order to make it taken in account by Boot when running `main()` and tests, create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` class as following:

```
class BeansInitializer : ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    override fun initialize(context: GenericApplicationContext) =
        beans().initialize(context)

}
```

And ultimately, declare this initializer in your `application.properties` file:

```
context.initializer.classes=com.example.BeansInitializer
```

You will find a full example [here](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional/tree/boot) and can also follow [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8115) about dedicated Spring Boot support for functional bean registration.

Comment: Two questions regarding your answer:

* This initialisation will be picked up by the test setup with using a `SpringRunner` with JUnit, right?
* Is there any other way of having this behaviour without having to create `properties` files, including this initialisation being picked up on tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes and not yet.

Comment: Side note: we are currently exploring full functional bean definition for Boot with Java or Kotlin DSL in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-fu incubator project.

Comment: What if I want to override a bean? I added allow-bean-definition-overriding: true and am trying to declare a test bean via @Bean but it seems to be ignored. I have tried an exact same setup(basically, just copy pasted) on a project withotu bean DSL and it worked.

Comment: Declaring the initializer like that will disable all other ones provided by spring boot, won't it?

Comment: Is that what your tests seems to indicate?

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it in Spring Boot would be :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args) {
        addInitializers(
                beans {
                    // Define your bean with Kotlin DSL here
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The drawback of that approach is that the initializer won't be taken in account for tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your beans in *Config.kt file and implement initalize method of **ApplicationContextInitializer** interface.

```
override fun initialize(applicationContext: GenericApplicationContext) {
    ....
}
```

Some bean definition here.

```
bean<XServiceImpl>("xService")

bean("beanName") {
        BeanConstructor(ref("refBeanName"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That same example project you mentioned has a [boot](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional/blob/boot/src/main/kotlin/functional/Beans.kt) git branch, with the BeanDefinitionDsl configuration for Spring Boot in a `Beans.kt` file. That is not how you should use git branches...