# How to use Kotlin beans dsl initializer in SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I have a simple application with several beans declared with kotlin beans dsl:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class App

val beans = beans {
    bean<A>()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MatchmakerApp>(*args) {
        addInitializers(beans)
    }
}

@RestController
class AppController(val a: A) {
    // some code
}

class A
```

and I have an integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class AppControllerTest {
    @Test
    fun dummyTest() {
        assert(true)
    }
}
```

Launching this test I'm getting

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name appController 
Caused by: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'A' available:`
```

It seems beans initializer was not invoked during `SpringBootTest` context creation.

What do we need to add kotlin bean dsl initializer in SpringBootTest?

The general way with `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ...)` does not work here, because it looks for classes.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46033685/256245 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use "Functional bean definition Kotlin DSL" with Spring Boot and Spring WebFlux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935931/how-to-use-functional-bean-definition-kotlin-dsl-with-spring-boot-and-spring-w)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `FuBeansInitializer` in the same package with `App` class in the test directory:

```kotlin
    class FuBeansInitializer : ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
        override fun initialize(context: GenericApplicationContext) = beans.initialize(context)
    }
```

add `context.initializer.classes` into test application.properties:

```
    context.initializer.classes=path.to.FuBeansInitializer
```

As a result, there will be nothing modified in the source files. And tests will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can even have multiple `ApplicationContextInitializer` and provide a comma separated list of them in your properties(order matters). This can be useful if you used Initializer in your main code and would want to override some of your beans using, again, bean definition dsl.