# Defining tomcat property in a test running with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-test

My application uses spring-boot 2.5.5.

I set a property for Tomcat at application startup to [allow encoded slash in `@PathVariable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058887/5539129) :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Everything works fine when I start the app, except in my integration tests :

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test-connected")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class GlobalFullTest {
```

When I debug the `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder` class : I see that the property `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH` is `null` when class is loaded, so a default value `false` is set.

I tried the following :

- Adding `System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");` in the `@BeforeAll` method of my test
- Adding `properties = { "org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true" }` in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
- Adding `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH: true` in my `application-test-connected.yaml`
- Using `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` :

```java
@Configuration
public class WebServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> customizer() {
        return factory -> factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true"));
    }

}
```

But none of these worked : when the property is retrieved by `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder`  class, its value is always `null`.

How could I set the property before the `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder` class is loaded ?

Comment: I would suggest to remove that line and figure out a way using a `TomcatCustomizer` instead. That way it works regardless of your environment.

Comment: `TomcatCustomizer ` doesn't seem to exist in spring-boot 2.5.5. I found a [WebServerFactoryCustomizer](https://www.baeldung.com/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-configurableembeddedservletcontainer-spring-boot) but even after setting the property with it, it is still null (corresponding code has been added to the original question)

Comment: You should call `setEncodedSolidusHandling` on the connector and set it to `decode`. The system property you are setting is actually deprecated (and used as a migration path).

Comment: @M.Deinum oh you're right ! I didn't know there were a _real_ programatic way to enable the slash decoding without the property. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [How to set environment variable or system property in spring tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306951/how-to-set-environment-variable-or-system-property-in-spring-tests)

### The simplest way

Follow [add static initializer in the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144312/7928721)

```java
...
class GlobalFullTest {
    static {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
    }
...
}
down side is we need to copy that for every test.
```

### Clean way

[create ApplicationContextInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305482/7928721), which can be reused [in the Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217768/7928721) and any other test.

```java
public class CustomApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
    }
}

...
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = CustomApplicationContextInitializer.class,...)
class GlobalFullTest {
...
```

Comment: this answer is a like diamond which I came across while walking on the pavement